# TFS build unable to locate the project file and dlls

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, tfs-2015, devops

I am trying to run a newly created Build in TFS but i am getting an error that :

```
The project file "D:\Binaries\vsts-agent-win7-x64-2.105.7\_work\1\s\CompanyA.Solution\..\..\..\Users\ihalarnkar=\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CompanyA.Project2\CompanyA.Project2\CompanyA.Project2.csproj" was not found.
```

Also some of the external dlls i am using for those i am getting no reference found. Like :

```
The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Does it mean i should have all the dlls i have referenced in the solution to be also installed on the tfs server? 
How about the solution? Every new project added should be available on the physical drive on the tfs server?

This is the 1st time i am configuring and using `DevOps` for a SharePoint Provider Hosted app. 
Kindly help.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with your solution references -- the project reference looks to be for the path `..\..\..\Users\ihalarnkar=\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CompanyA.Project2\CompanyA.Project2\CompanyA.Project2.csproj`.

You'll need to go through your project files and fix the references.